# why the ManipulationDelta in the WP7.1 didn't work very well?

Tags: windows-phone-7

As the title says, when upgrade to the Windows Phone 7.1 It seems the ManipulationDelta do not fire as frequency as the version of Windows Phone 7.

eg:
  I have a ScrollViewer, and there are some controls in it. I set the ScrollViewer's ManipulationMode is Control. When i Vertical scrolling, the ManipulationDelta event didn't fire at all. ThereMore, when I Horizontal scrolling,the ManipulationDelta event fired. I don't kown why this happed. How can I use  ManipulationDelta event in the ScrollViewer.

Comment: Finally I worked out my problem using the event: MouseMove of the ScrollViewer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It changed in Mango.  Details can be found here:
[On the Silverlight for Windows Phone Performance Team Blog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/slmperf/archive/2011/06/02/listbox-scrollviewer-performance-improvement-for-mango-and-how-it-impacts-your-existing-application.aspx) as well as a bunch of
[research and workarounds here](http://wieser-software.blogspot.com/2012/01/scrollviewer-inertia-and.html)